# Merge objects in JSON lists using JQ

Tags: json, jq

I want to merge two JSON files, where the objects in the base file (A) are augmented by matching objects in file (B), but not overwritten where A and B have different values for the same key.

For example, I have a JSON file (A) with contents like

```
[
  {
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": "apple"
  },
  {
    "name": "beta",
    "value": "banana"
  },
  {
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": "guava"
  }
]
```

and a second JSON file (B), with the same basic structure but optionally with additional keys (`metadata` in this example, but it could be anything):

```
[
  {
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": "apple",
    "metadata": {
      "types": [
        "granny"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "beta",
    "value": "blueberry"
  },
  {
    "name": "omega",
    "value": "orange"
  }
]
```

I want to merge the two lists together, key/values from objects in B are added into the same object (matched by `name`) in A.  My JQ to achieve this is like:

```
jq -s '[ .[0][] as $a | .[1][] as $b | select ($a.name == $b.name) | $a * $b ]' b.json a.json
```

This works to add the `metadata` into A and retains A's values for other keys.  However, `gamma` is missing from the result.  From the example above, I want a result where:

- alpha should have the metadata
- beta should be banana, not blueberry.
- gamma should be in the final list
- omega should NOT be in the final list
- Order of objects in the list should be maintained.

I want this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": "apple"
    "metadata": {
      "types": [
        "granny"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "beta",
    "value": "banana"
  },
  {
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": "guava"
  }
]
```

How do I adapt this query to also include top level objects from A, but not from B?

Comment: What if file B had name `alpha`, value `ananas` (different from file A), and some metadata (not present in file A)? Should the value also be copied over, or just the metadata? Also: Is it guaranteed that each name is unique (within one file)?

Comment: No, just the metadata key.  Yes, each name is guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If names are guaranteed to be unique within one file, you could temporarily turn file A into an `INDEX`, so checking the containedness of a `.name` becomes a matter of checking keys with `has`. Then, iterate over the items of file B using `reduce` on `input[]`, and if a name is present as key, update the according field by adding its old value to the current item (order matters). Finally, revert the object structure back to an array by collecting all field values into an array, using `[.[]]`.

```bash
jq 'reduce input[] as $i (INDEX(.name);
  if has($i.name) then .[$i.name] |= $i + . end
) | [.[]]' fileA.json fileB.json
```

```json
[
  {
    "name": "alpha",
    "value": "apple",
    "metadata": {
      "types": [
        "granny"
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "beta",
    "value": "banana"
  },
  {
    "name": "gamma",
    "value": "guava"
  }
]
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/ybgr2NojOAs)

Comment: Great, thank you, this does exactly the job.  Took me a little while to understand what it was doing!

Answer (score 1):

If we treat the first file as a list of elements, and the second file as a lookup from which we have to retrieve the matching values for each of those elements, then all we need to do is match each element to its corresponding element in the lookup ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/p0hEpyfYrvV)):

```
INDEX(.[0][] ; .name) as $elements  |
INDEX(.[1][] ; .name) as $lookup    |
$elements | keys []   as $key       |
$elements[$key]       as $value     |
$lookup[$key]         as $match     | ( $match // {} ) * $value
```

A few things to note:

- If the corresponding element is missing in the lookup, we use an empty object as the matched element.
- We ensure that the element's original values are one the right side of `*` operator so that it's attribute values supersede the matched object's attribute values.
- We trigger the iteration on each key with this expression `$elements | keys []`
- The `INDEX` function converts the original arrays into keyed objects so that they are easy to work with.

Comment: Thanks!  This works too, interesting approach!  I'll test this to see which is faster between this and the accepted answer below and share my findings.

Answer (score 1):

Using the same basic ideas of treating the first file as list elements and the second file as lookup from which we have to retrieve matching values (as discussed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77312537/84940)), here is a more terse solution ([demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wRRPjrOCGJi)):

```
  ( .[0][] ) as $element 
| ( .[1] | map(select(.name == $element.name)) [] // {} ) as $match 
| $match * $element
```

Comment: This is close, but not quite right.  This will make beta = blueberry, but it should be banana.

Comment: @Jumwah - Thanks for pointing it out; I was missing some parenthesis. I corrected the answer and updated the link for the demo.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
jq 'map(. + (input | map(select(.name == .name)))[0])' jsonA.json jsonB.json
```

Comment: This produces an error `error (at <unknown>): break`

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**